# Spring Boot REST with JWT and blocking Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, jwt

I want to implement a REST Service with Spring Boot (language is Kotlin), secured by Spring Security and JWT (jsonwebtoken.io):

Major classes are the configuration (yes, csrf is disabled):

```
@Bean
fun filterChain(
    http: HttpSecurity,
    authenticationManager: UserAuthenticationManager
): SecurityFilterChain
{
    return http
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
        .and()
            .addFilterAfter(
                JwtAuthenticationFilter(jwtTokenService, authenticationManager, securityProperties),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            .addFilterAfter(
                JwtAuthorizationFilter(jwtTokenService, authenticationManager, securityProperties),
                JwtAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
        .build()
}
```

the token service:

```
@Component
class JwtTokenService(
    @Autowired val securityProperties: SecurityProperties,
    @Autowired val userService: UserService
)
{
    private var key: Key? = null

    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64.decode(securityProperties.secret))
    }

    fun generateToken(user: UserDetails): String
    {
        val now = Instant.now()
        val expiryDate = now.plusSeconds(securityProperties.expiration)

        return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(user.username)
            .setIssuedAt(Date.from(now))
            .setExpiration(Date.from(expiryDate))
            .signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
            .compact()
    }

    fun getAuthentication(token: String): Authentication?
    {
        return try {
            val claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(key)
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(securityProperties.tokenPrefix, ""))
            val user = userService.loadUserByUsername(claims.body.subject)
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, token, user.authorities)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

the authentication filter for the login (this works also with return code 200, but only because `continueChainBeforeSuccessfulAuthentication` is false, when set to true the filter fails):

```
class JwtAuthenticationFilter(
    private val jwtTokenService: JwtTokenService,
    private val authenticationManager: UserAuthenticationManager,
    private val securityProperties: SecurityProperties
): AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
    AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/login", "POST"), authenticationManager)
{
    override fun attemptAuthentication(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse
    ): Authentication
    {
        val loginRequest = ObjectMapper()
            .readValue(request.inputStream, LoginRequest::class.java)
        val authenticationToken = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            loginRequest.username, loginRequest.password)
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken)
    }

    override fun successfulAuthentication(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        chain: FilterChain,
        authResult: Authentication
    ) {
        val user = authResult.principal as User
        val token = jwtTokenService.generateToken(user)

        response.addHeader(
            securityProperties.headerString,
            securityProperties.tokenPrefix + token)
    }
}
```

and the authorization filter:

```
class JwtAuthorizationFilter(
    private val jwtTokenService: JwtTokenService,
    authenticationManager: UserAuthenticationManager,
    private val securityProperties: SecurityProperties
) : BasicAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager)
{
    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    )
    {
        val header = request.getHeader(securityProperties.headerString)
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(securityProperties.tokenPrefix)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
            return
        }    

        jwtTokenService.getAuthentication(header)?.let { authentication ->
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = authentication
        }

        // continue with authenticated user
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}
```

In my understanding, when I set the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication`, the request is authorized - but it get's blocked. So I set the Spring Security log level to `TRACE` and executed a POST to `/api/employees`:

```
  Securing POST /api/employees/
  Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13)
  Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
  Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/13)
  Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13)
  Invoking LogoutFilter (5/13)
  Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
  Invoking JwtAuthenticationFilter (6/13)
  Invoking JwtAuthorizationFilter (7/13)
  Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
  Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/13)
  Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/13)
  Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/13)
  Invoking SessionManagementFilter (11/13)
  Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=at.oebb.tools.routing.user.User@7a529298, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[at.oebb.tools.routing.user.User$$Lambda$788/0x00000008014bd130@57cd77e2]]
  Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/1)
  Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
  Invoking AuthorizationFilter (13/13)
  Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@61cc275c]
  Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@61cc275c] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@332aabc6
  Secured POST /api/employees/
```

and it seems that `AuthorizationFilter` is blocking me, even with an existing authentication in the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication. Can anyone help me to understand why?

I mostly followed this [implementation](https://github.com/osahner/kotlin-spring-boot-rest-jpa-jwt-starter).

Comment: There are two layers to spring security - authentication ("do we know and like you?") and authorization ("are you allowed to do this?"). Your authorization filter seems like a second authentication filter. I would expect such a class to take a JWT token and do verifications on claims it has.

Comment: Added the JwtTokenService class which shows the missing parts

Comment: i do recommend that you read the JWT chapter in the spring security docs, spring security has had built in JWT handling since 2017 and most tutorials out there havn't even read the docs. I would recommend using the built in JWT features.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html and here is an example https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo

Comment: Thanks for the links and the info, I will definitely try this approach. However, I could not find how to generate a token via a login endpoint in both links. Do i have a wrong understanding here as well?

Comment: I assume I still can use my adopted JwtAuthenticationFilter or just a login endpoint when I don't want to use any external authorization server.